# Mysql INSERT INTO SELECT statement with CASE

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to insert multiple rows (three) of data into my database using one `INSERT` statement?

```
INSERT INTO dvd_price
( SELECT
, (SELECT max(dvd_price_id) + 1 FROM dvd_price) --dvd_price_id
, d.dvd_id                                      --dvd_id
, 2                                             --rental amount
, '1-day'                                       --time rented for
FROM dvd d);
```

The above will insert it once for `1-day`; I'd like to have the same statement also insert the data for `2-day` and `3-day`, with corresponding values (`2` incremented once for each subsequent insert) for the rental amount.

Comment: Are you trying to get the same `dvd_price_id` vale for all three, or increment it for each one?

Comment: Increment it for each one.

Comment: And is `dvd_price_id` the table's primary key?

Comment: I'm trying to increment the dvd_price_id, the primary key, by one each time an insert goes into the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, you should *not* be attempting to retrieve the next insert id by calling `MAX(dvd_price_id) + 1`. That is not immune to race conditions, and can potentially cause problems as it is not reliable.  If you do not have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` on `dvd_price_id` already, you are advised to add one and let the RDBMS handle the increment for you.

```
ALTER TABLE dvd_price MODIFY dvd_price_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Now, you don't need to worry about the `dvd_price_id` at all in the `INSERT`.  To get all three values for `1-day, 2-day, 3-day` you may create a cartesian product by joining against a list of those static values. That will result in one each of the day values for every row currently in the table.

```
INSERT INTO dvd_price (dvd_id, rental_amount, time_rented_for)
  SELECT
    dvd_id,
    2 AS rental_amount,
    rental_period
  FROM
    dvd
    /* join a subquery which creates a list of 'N-day' strings using
       SELECT 'value' UNION SELECT 'value'.....
       With no ON clause, it will do this for every row in `dvd`
     */
    CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT '1-day' AS rental_period 
      UNION SELECT '2-day' AS rental_period
      UNION SELECT '3-day' AS rental_period
  ) rental_periods
```

Test this first using only the `SELECT` portion of the query, without the `INSERT`.

Here is a demonstration of how it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0862/1

Comment: @eggyal You are correct. I just had to check MySQL docs to see if it actually supported `CROSS JOIN`, and it does treat it equivalently to `INNER JOIN`.